# How click the parent class if the child href matches the requirement

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I've tired to find the right selenium code to get click the main parent class if the following requirements exist in the class :

```html
Parent Class

<div class ="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item" data-sqe="item">

Child class

<a data-sqe="link" href= all urls that is printed in python.>

Child class contains this element
<div class = "_1gkBDw _2O43P5">
<div class = "_1HvBLA">
<div class = "_3ao649" data-sqe="ad"> Ad</div>
```

[image]

Here is the code bellow

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv

import time
url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:/users/Francabicon/Desktop/Bots/others/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(0.8)

# select language
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="language-selection__list"]/button').click()
time.sleep(3)

# scroll few times to load all items 
for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300)")
    time.sleep(0.1)

# get all links (without clicking)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@data-sqe="link"]')
print('len:', len(all_items))

all_urls = []

j = 0
k = 45

for item in all_items:
    url = item.get_attribute('href')
    all_urls.append(url)

print(all_urls)

a= len(all_urls)



# now use links
i = 0


while i <= 4 :
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item' and @data-sqe='item']//a[@class='link' and @href= all_urls[i]]"))).click()
    i+=1
```

I've tried to locate:
   -Div the whole class
   -locate classes and the href individualy
   -click the first five columns
but it all always fails.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Users/Asashin/Desktop/Bots/click test 7.py", line 52, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item' and @data-sqe='item']//a[@class='link' and @href= all_urls[i]]"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Can I be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made couple of changes.

> 1. When you are fetching `href` values you are getting complete url and not the url you are seeing in DOM so you need to remove the preceding values in order to verify later.
> 2. In the last while loop `all_urls[i]` is variable you need passed it as variable not string.
> 3. Once you click each link you need to come back to the parent page again by using `driver.back()`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:/users/Francabicon/Desktop/Bots/others/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
# select language
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="language-selection__list"]/button'))).click()
time.sleep(3)

# scroll few times to load all items
for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300)")
    time.sleep(0.1)

# get all links (without clicking)
all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@data-sqe="link"]')
print('len:', len(all_items))

all_urls = []

j = 0
k = 45

for item in all_items:
    # This give you whole url of the anchor tag
    url = item.get_attribute('href')
    # You need to remove the preceding values in order to verify href later for clicking
    urlfinal=url.split('https://shopee.com.my')[1]
    all_urls.append(urlfinal)

print(all_urls)
a= len(all_urls)

# now use links
i = 0

while i <= 4 :
    #Identify the parent tag by child tag use following Xpath.
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item' and @data-sqe='item'][.//a[@data-sqe='link' and @href='" + all_urls[i] +"']]"))).click()
    driver.back()
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get parent element:

```
child_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-sqe="link"]')
parent_element = child_element.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "shopee-search-item-result__item")][1]')
```

How to get element with specific child:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('div[contains(@class, "shopee-search-item-result__item") and .//a[@data-sqe="link"]]')
```